# Open Cv installation problem

Tags: opencv, libav

I am following [this](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/) link for installing OpenCv but on the make step I came across an error:

```
home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:98:7: 
error: ‘CODEC_ID_H264’ was not declared in this scope 
{ CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('H', '2', '6', '4') },
```

On asking, someone pointed out an excellent explanation which was something like this:

> This is because libav has changed API and removed some stuff it's
>   still used in OpenCV. Ubuntu 14.10 uses libav API version 11 and
>   OpenCV still uses API version 9. The problem is that `CODEC_ID_*` was
>   changed to `AV_CODEC_ID_*`.

Now how can I fix this problem, please help me?

Is there some kind of patch or something, already have wasted 3 full days in just trying to figure out the problem, now I know the problem but can't find the solution?